# Network tools, functional programming style

Tags: python, functional-programming, ping, traceroute

I'm gonna be honest here: when it comes to functional programming, I never went further than reading about it or solving simple problems. Despite loving the idea of concise, easy-to-maintain source code, I never found a reason to use the paradigm. Until today: I want to implement a couple of network tools (like `traceroute` or `ping`) in Python, trying to be as "functional" as possible (with the help of `scapy`, `functools` and `itertools`. First, `ping`:

```
def tcp_ping(destination_ip, destination_port, n_probes=10, timeout=1):
    source_ports = [randint(49152, 65535) for i in range(n_probes)]
    probes = IP(dst=destination_ip)/TCP(sport=source_ports, dport=destination_port, flags='S')
    responses = map(partial(sr, timeout=timeout, verbose=0), probes)

    answered = filter(lambda x: len(x[0]) > 0, responses)
    lost = filter(lambda x: x not in answered, responses)
    rtts = map(lambda x: int(1000 * (x[0][0][1].time - x[0][0][0].sent_time)), answered) or [0]

    return dict(loss=float(len(lost))/n_probes,
                min_rtt=min(rtts),
                max_rtt=max(rtts),
                avg_rtt=mean(rtts),
                std_rtt=std(rtts))
```

And then, `traceroute`:

```
def takeuntil(predicate, iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        yield x
        if predicate(x):
            break

def traceroute_probes(destination_ip, destination_port):
    ttl = 1
    while ttl <= 255:
        p = IP(dst=destination_ip, ttl=ttl)/TCP(dport=destination_port, flags='S')
        yield p
        ttl = ttl + 1

def is_finalhop(x):
    return (len(x[0]) > 0 and
            not x[0][0][1].haslayer('ICMP'))

def hop_ip_latency(x):
    if len(x[0]) > 0:
        return (x[0][0][0].ttl,
                x[0][0][1].src,
                max(0, int(1000 * (x[0][0][1].time - x[0][0][0].sent_time))))
    else:
        return (x[1][0][0].ttl, '*', 0)

def tcp_traceroute(destination_ip, destination_port, timeout=1):
    responses = takeuntil(is_finalhop,
                          imap(partial(sr, timeout=timeout, verbose=0),
                               traceroute_probes(destination_ip,
                                                 destination_port)))
    return map(hop_ip_latency, responses)
```

Now, the questions:

- How can we make this code more "functional"?
- How can I add more complexity (e.g. stopping the `traceroute` after three timeouts in a row) without introducing unnecessary side-effects?
- How can I change `sr` (the interface to the world) behavior (e.g. varying the timeout in `ping` depending on the RTT) without falling into a imperative/object-oriented trap?
- Is there a pure(r) functional language that would be adequate to implement network tools, while also forcing me to be "more functional"?
- Who forgot to add `takeuntil` to Python's `itertools`?

Comment: There is a `takeuntil` in itertools - it's called `takewhile`

Comment: Wow, you sure did go all the way there. Not that I would call this being readable. OCaml is very functional; if it's just for fun, go for it.

Comment: `takewhile` takes until the condition is `False`, Yuushi. `takeuntil` takes until the condition is `True` - it's not the same.

Comment: Why wouldn't you call it being readable, Michał?

Comment: Please delete this question and ask on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)